# The process cannot access the file 'C:\some\Desktop\2011-11-23 15.47.36.jpg' because it is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net, binary, arrays

I Am trying to use this function to Get the Byte From It To Send It To DataBase

```
Public Function GetBinary(ByVal Path As String) As Byte()
    Dim fStream As New FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
    Dim fLen As Integer = fStream.Length
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)
    Dim data As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fLen)
    Return data
End Function
```

But When I Use It , It Gives An Error Seems To Be THE file I've selected is being opened by another Application ,,,

Error Message >

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\LOAI\Desktop\2011-11-23 15.47.36.jpg' because it is being used by another process.
```

How Can I Select A file Without This Error And Take The Bytes From the Image

BEST Regards

Comment: Are you accessing that file from another computer? Or is it on your local computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are specifying `FileShare.None`.  By doing so, you are making it so the file cannot open if any other process also has that file open.  From the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx):

> Declines sharing of the current file. Any request to open the file (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed.

If you just want to open the file read-only, regardless if any other process is accessing the file at the same time, you probably want to specify `FileShare.Read`:

> Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading. If this flag is not specified, any request to open the file for reading (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed. However, even if this flag is specified, additional permissions might still be needed to access the file.